# ANDROID URL DIRECT APP SAYS "web page not available", ON EMULATOR IT SAYS "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS"

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to *Android*... I use *Eclipse Juno* IDE.

My aim is to just direct my app to a web page on opening it. I use `WebView` concept.
Have given all permissions correctly(upto my knowledge). Java Code seems error free on eclipse.

But, ON EMULATOR IT SAYS "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS".
When installed the app on mobile, the APP SAYS "web page not available"

I tried by changing the url as `www.google.co.in`, to test my code, despite giving my preferred url. For that also it tells the same.
Kindly help me sort this problems out...
It'd really be helpful...
Thanks in advance...

Below given is my complete code from *AndroidManifest.xml* to *MyActivity.java*:

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="anroid.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/web_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView Browser;

     private class WebClient extends WebViewClient
     {
         @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
         }

     }

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Browser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
         Browser.loadUrl("www.google.co.in");    
     }

     @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch(keyCode)
                {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(Browser.canGoBack()){
                        Browser.goBack();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        backButtonHandler();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
     public void backButtonHandler() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
           // Setting Dialog Message

            alertDialog.setTitle("");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon);
            alertDialog.setMessage("Exit Now?");

             // Setting Icon to Dialog
            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Exit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
            });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
        // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works after some minor changes in my **MainActivity.java**. Below is the edited code:

```
package com.example.webview;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView Browser;

    private class WebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Browser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        Browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // Give your desired URL below
        Browser.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com");
        Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
        Browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()});
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(Browser.canGoBack())
                {
                    Browser.goBack();
                }
                else
                {
                    backButtonHandler();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void backButtonHandler() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title 
        // Setting Dialog Message

        alertDialog.setTitle("");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon1);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Exit Now?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog 
         // Setting Positive "Yes" Button

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { finish();
    }
  });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Write your code here to invoke NO event

                dialog.cancel();
            }
  });

        // Showing Alert Message

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the full adress something like :

```
Browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in");
```

All I know that only "www" does not work.

Comment: Yup... Thanks for your reply.. I've already tried with that, but forgot to mention in my question. It doesn't help too.